Defending a patent, licensing
I am a small entity, incorporated for the sole purpose of developing a great invention. I am seeking advice on how best to proceed. If ‘great’ is perceived or real will be answered by a prototype.
Applying for one patent is doable but supporting a litigation is likely out of reach as well as filing for many countries. For that purpose, I would think that a licensee of the invention, having the clout and reputation, might defend the patent?
Possible countries to file are: US, UK, Germany, France, Italy, Spain, Sweden, China, Russia, S. Korea, Brazil, Australia, Canada, S. Afrika. Too many?
Would a company enter a licensing agreement if a patent has not been applied for? I would think not, or are such things negotiable? Likely at least one application would have to be filed for the status of patent pending where a provisional US application would qualify? Having a US provisional I should still be asking for the signing of an NDA since the provisional expires after one year. What amounts may be expected as a down payment when licensing that may be used for patenting costs.
One firm that I had visited said it is willing to reassess its interest and asked to come back with a working prototype which is in progress. I have various demonstrator models to show mechanical workability but not necessarily durability. A prototype is a bit more involved. A firm in the field would likely have a prototype running within a short time. Perhaps a first company that signs on for licensing will be willing to defend the invention in court? Is that a possible scenario?
Should I apply in the US? Some people think, if one plans to file the PCT in any case, best would be to start your protection by filing first at the PCT? Your thoughts?
For lower initial cost, would first the US provisional, and then the PCT make sense? Or would the provisional not be needed? What costs are involved at the PCT? Will the PCT check for patentability automatically or is a request needed? Is it possible to ask the PCT not to make a search? I searched myself and found lots of patents but none describes my invention and the product is not being marketed. As I am confident that the system per my design will work and would be marketable, it is likely that my solution has not been patented or was not applied for.
In short, how does an inventor of limited resources protect and market a great invention?
Thank you for your guidance and recommendations.

This site works best when one question is posted at a time.

Also, licensing questions are specifically off topic on this site.
